# What is the purpose of the DataSize property for a NameColumn in SSAS?

Tags: ssis, ssas

I have a dimension with an an attribute called CustomerDaysPastDue. I had to create a composite KeyColumn which then necessitated that I specify a NameColumn. For some reason it will only let me specify as a WCHAR which I'm not sure why this? Additionally I believe that I need to specify the DataSize but I'm not sure what would be affected if I omit that value. The KeyColumn is an integer, so I ended up setting the DataSize as 14 (max negative value of integer with commas... -2,147,483,648). I then reduced the DataSize to 3, deployed and executed my package but the data wasn't truncated though I expected it would be.

Answer (score -1):

A composite key combines two or more columns uniquely identifying a row in a table. You have likely created a composite key in your dimension, which means you use more than one column for uniqueness. The NameColumn is used to specify the name for each dimension member. In your case, it appears that the NameColumn data type is specified as WCHAR, which stands for Wide Character String.

The WCHAR data type is used to store Unicode characters. SSAS dimensions typically require unique names for each dimension member, and since Unicode supports a wide range of characters from different languages and symbol sets, using WCHAR ensures that you can have unique names with a broader range of characters.

The DataSize property is used to specify the maximum size of the data in bytes for string columns. In the case of WCHAR, it represents the maximum number of characters, not bytes. Since you're using WCHAR for the NameColumn, specify the maximum number of characters allowed for the NameColumn's data size.

Setting the DataSize for the NameColumn will not cause any data truncation. The DataSize property is used for validation purposes but does not truncate or modify the data. If a value exceeds the specified DataSize, SSIS may raise a warning or error during execution, but it won't truncate the data.

Suppose you want to truncate data during the data flow in SSIS. In that case, you'll need to explicitly use transformation components like "Derived Column" or "Data Conversion" to truncate the data as per your requirements.